# print elements in decreasing order of ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, string, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

The code here accepts 5 Strings from user and i want them to save from last to first i.e. first input to last position and last input to first position in ArrayList . As much as i understand, I should define the size of ArrayList before loop but i maybe wrong.

For Example:- if the user inputs `String0` ,`String1`,`String2`,`String3`,`String4` then it should be  saved in this form of ArrayList `[String4,String3,String2,String1,String0]`.

The way i am doing it like this and
 I am getting error as
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0`  after first user input.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i=4;i>=0;i--){
        list.add(i,reader.readLine());
    }
    for (String aList : list)
    {
        System.out.println(aList);
    }

}
}
```

Thanks a lot ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the first line, there is nothing in the `ArrayList` yet, but you are attempting to `add` the line at the index `4`, which doesn't exist yet, causing the exception.  The [`add` method javadocs (taking an index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) state:

> **Throws:**
>
> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

If you want to add it before all other elements, then always add it at index `0`.

```
list.add(0,reader.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the size of an arraylist.  An array list is a dynamic array where the size can change dynamically.

```
list.add(0,reader.readLine());

for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){
    list.add(0,reader.readLine());
}
```

This will add each next element at position 0 moving everything back 1.
You were trying to insert at position 4 when the arraylist is size 0.

Answer (score 0):

once you add your strings to list you can sort the list in decreasing order.

**Approach-1:**
Use Collections.reverseOrder() method along with Collections.sort() in order to sort the list in decreasing order like below

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

**Approach-2:** you can sort the list in ascending order first and then reverse it

```
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
```